# Managed VM not running on production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, managed-vm

I'm trying to deploy a managed VM application to google cloud platform and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying).
Deployed Version: converter:dev.386894231648366298
```

Also, a 503 http error is returned from the module.

The `app.yaml` is:

```
application: XXXXXXX
module:      converter
version: "dev"
runtime: python27
vm: true
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: urls.application
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

The `url.py` is:

```
import webapp2
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('ok')
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

I use a Dockerfile with:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat
ADD . /app/
```

gcloud version:

```
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.75
app 2015.08.23
app-engine-python 1.9.25
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.21
beta 2015.08.17
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2015.08.23
core-nix 2015.06.02
gae-python-launcher-mac 1.9.18
gcloud 2015.08.23
gcutil-nix 1.16.5
gsutil 4.13
gsutil-nix 4.12
preview 2015.08.23
preview-extensions-darwin-x86_64 0.10.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What zone are you running in?

Comment: us-central1-f This is what I see in the gcloud output [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/crave-srv/zones/us-central1-f/instances/gae-builder-vm-dev]

Comment: What version of gcloud are you running? and Are you running any other VM's in the project?

Comment: I added it to the question, and I'm running only one project.

Comment: But to confirm, you are running no other **VM's** in the project.

Comment: Oh, also are you in free trial? Or have you activated billing on the project?

Comment: I'm running 2 other vms, not managed.

Comment: The project is billing enabled.

Comment: How many cores total are you using?

Comment: 1 standard instance **manual_scaling:
  instances: 1**

Comment: Alright, I got nothing.  I would advise you to spin up another project in a different zone and see if you get the same error.